# ASP.NET Core API - Dynamic Routing (Make API route behave like "one-parameter query string")

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Aloha :D
I would like to create a dynamic route binding.
What I mean by this, is basically replacing the Query String with a dynamic route.

Example:
Instead of this:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/documents?templatename=individualemploymentagreement
```

this:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/documents/individualemploymentagreement
```

**Note:** after "http://localhost:5000/api/documents/" I want to put anything I want, but this route will always be used and what comes after should be used like a variable. Obviously, this will lead to a non-existing API Route at the moment. But is there any way to deal with this?

**Note 2:** The reasons I want to use this are:
- According to RESTful services "rules", query strings should be used just for queries, In this case I'm not using a query, I'm calling a generic document service, which however, treats every document slightly different when needed. So query strings are not recommended in my case.
- This service will deal with hundreds of document types, so I can't really make a different path / api for each one of them. So this is not recommended as well.

**My code** (In which I'm using a query string for {templateName}:

```
namespace DocumentGenerator.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/{controller}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase
    {
      //useless details

        [HttpPost]  
        public async Task<IActionResult> Generate([FromQuery] string templateName, [FromBody] object properties)
        {
            // according to {templateName} do this or that...
            // useless details
        }
     }
}
```

**What I would want in code**:

```
 namespace DocumentGenerator.Api.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/{controller}")]
        [ApiController]
        public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase
        {
          //useless details

            [HttpPost("{templateName}"]  
            public async Task<IActionResult> Generate([FromBody] object properties)
            {
                // according to {templateName} do this or that...
                // useless details
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: That's not what `dynamic route binding` means. Routing is already dynamic and what you ask is how routing already works. In the default route template, `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`, the '{id}` part in a route *already* contains everything after the second slash. If you called the action parameter `id` instead of `templateName` you'd be able to get it directly. What you ask is either *rewriting* the URL or *hard-coding* some of the parameters - eg using `Generate` as the action and `{templateName}` as the parameter instead of `{id}`

Comment: Have you tried `[HttpPost("{templateName}"] public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(string templateName, [FromBody] object properties)`  or `[HttpPost("/documents/{"templateName}"] .....`?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, you're right. That's how it basically works. Of course i used it before like this "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}".  I just didn't make the connection. Thank you.

Comment: Neither did I at first - I posted the first comment and then remembered I've seen this before only to find [an exact example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#specifying-attribute-route-optional-parameters-default-values-and-constraints). Looks you can even use `[Route("/dog{token}cat")])` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the parameter name as a route attribute value in HttpPost :

```
[HttpPost("{templateName}"]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(string templateName, [FromBody] object properties)
{
}
```

or even

```
[HttpPost("/api/documents/{templateName}"]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(string templateName, [FromBody] object properties)
{
}
```